# Best way to preload 50 questions in html for a mobile quiz app?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cordova

What would be the simplest and easiest way to 
  to preload 50 quiz type questions in html for a mobile quiz app?

If the user loses wifi and internet access I wanted them to be able to 
press the submit button when they regain wifi/3-4g access again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd preload the questions by including them in the web page as a Javascript object.

```
var questions = [
  {"q": "Why did the Chicken cross the road"},
  {a: [
        "It was bored",
         "It was following the goat."
      ]
  }
}
```

You can use AJAX to submit the answers.  If it errors out, save the answers using [localstorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).  Uset `.setTimeout()` to wake up every few seconds and see if submitting works.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a simpler way would be to just put all the questions on the page (in html) and then as your user walks through them you can hide and show them as you need to.  When the user submits, if it fails, you can place a waiting icon and keep trying with setTimeout.  As Jeremy pointed out you could also store the answers in localstorage in the event the window is closed.

The best answer for you really depends on your overall architecture, but you don't have to use javascript or json to load all the questions depending on your technical level.

A simple mockup (that is not entirely functional):

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/naMg5/

Comment: "Probably a simpler way would be to just put all the questions on the page (in html) and then as your user walks through them you can hide and show them as you need to."  I am testing this with show/hiding divs too.. thanks

Comment: No problem.  The answer to the best is very subjective. Hopefully you solve the issue with whichever way is best for you.